# Does a Self-Hosted Windows Forms WCF Service need to be on a background thread?

Tags: multithreading, winforms, wcf, msmq, self-hosting

I've searched and searched and seen questions similar, but not specific, to this.

I am doing a msmq-based request/response WCF setup, where the Windows Forms client sends a msmq WCF message to a service, which runs a long running process, and uses a string addressed passed by the client to put status updates in a queue on the client.  The Client should self-host a WCF MSMQ based service that picks up and responds to status messages.

The problem is, even with opening the Host in Program.cs and waiting to close it until FormClose, is that, at startup, the Windows Form will process ONE message that is in the queue (leftover from a previous run), and no more.  It feels like some kind of threading issue.  However, all examples I've seen seem to act like it's okay to do a host.open() in the form create or startup, and a host.close() on shutdown, and it should pick up messages just fine.

If anyone has an example of doing this where the WCF incoming msmq messages will be picked up whenever they arrive, while the UI stays repsonsive, please let me know.

For what it's worth, to make sure the service and queue were configured correctly, I did a simple WCF standalone library project with the same config and source files, and it processes all messages in the queue just fine.  It's just trying to self-host in a WinForms app that is not working properly.

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public partial class frmStart : Form, IExportStatus
{

    private void frmStart_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (host == null || host.State != CommunicationState.Opened)
        {

            host = new ServiceHost(this);
            // ServiceHostGlobal.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IExportStatus), Binding, endpointAddress);
            // Open the ServiceHostBase to create listeners and start listening for order status messages.
            host.Open();

        }

    }
```

Comment: It is hard to understand what you mean without some code.  I think you need to examine your ServiceBehaviorAttribute.ConcurrencyMode  and ServiceBehaviorAttribute.InstanceContextMode settings.

Comment: Take a look at FormHost from IDesign [here](http://idesign.net/Downloads). There are other good examples there too.

Comment: I would be happy to post the code.  But I think you'd find it boring because it's basically the same 'example' code you see everywhere.  Petar, I have his book and have downloaded his example.  The problem with his stuff is first, it's pretty old and won't build in VS2012 -- His example of a FormHost won't build because he didn't include all the code in the solution.  He kinda needs to get it rebuilt and re-uploaded.  Second, his libraries are overkill, and do custom logging and what-not against SQL Server (I'm in an Oracle shop)...lots of work to get his examples to work.

Comment: Darrin, I'll investigate both of these.  Did a little experimentation to no avail, but I wasn't really sure they were the answer in the first place.  I'll go back to the docs and try to understand them better.

Comment: @RandyMagruder: When you open serviceHost on UI thread - it captures the `SynchronizationContext` and service becomes bound to that UI thread. Regardless of your concurrency mode, service methods run only on UI thread. To disable this behavior you can mark the service with - `[ServiceBehavior(UseSynchronizationContext = false)]`